# How to manage binary files storage in C++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, fstream

I need to correctly manage binary files streams for copying and pasting compressed files with `.zip` extension.
I'm actually trying to make a simple test project: I would like to copy `./src/Directory.zip` in `./dest` directory initially empty.
The code compiling is correctly done, but at the end of the program the destination directory is still empty and I don't know for which reason.
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

std::vector<BYTE> readFile(const char* filename)
{
    // open the file:
    std::streampos fileSize;
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // get its size:
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // read the data:
    std::vector<BYTE> fileData(fileSize);
    file.read((char*) &fileData[0], fileSize);
    return fileData;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<BYTE> fileData = readFile("./src/Directory.zip");
    std::ofstream destFile;
    destFile = std::ofstream("./dest/Directory.zip", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if ( !destFile )
        std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
    destFile.write( (char*) &fileData[0], sizeof(BYTE)*fileData.size() );
    destFile.close();
    
    return 0;
}
```

I know this could be simply done with `std::filesystem::copy_file`  or other high-level functions, but these binary files will be sent through a socket from a server to a client. Firstly I would like to let this work in a local directory.

I've just followed the advice in the answer and I get this error:
`No such file or directory`

Comment: You don't do any error checking. You could try `if(!destFile) std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';` which should print an error message if something went wrong.

Comment: Why is it `std::fstream` and not `std::ofstream`?

Comment: I edited first post

Comment: The code looks OK. It compiles and runs properly on MSVC. Maybe the file you are trying to copy, or the destination directory is missing.

Comment: I solved, it was just a problem of the directory name.
Thank you so much for your support guys!